# failing to scrape links from google chrome

Tags: python, html, hyperlink, scrape

My code is opening the tab, searching for the theme and closing, but it is not sending me the links that it should gather.

```
from selenium import webdriver

pesquisa = input ("o que você quer pesquisar: ")


def get_results(search_term):
    url = "https://www.startpage.com"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_id("q")
    search_box.send_keys(search_term)
    search_box.submit()
    try:
        links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ol[@class='web_regular_results']//div//a")
    except:
        links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div//a")
    results = []
    for link in links:
        href = link.get_attribute("href")
        print(href)
        results.append(href)
    driver.close()
    return results
    
get_results(pesquisa)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver

pesquisa = input ("o que você quer pesquisar: ")


def get_results(search_term):
    url = "https://www.startpage.com"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_id("q")
    search_box.send_keys(search_term)
    search_box.submit()
    try:
        links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ol[@class='web_regular_results']//div//a")
    except:
        links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div//a")
        pass            # Here you have to write pass to make following statements run
    results = []
    for link in links:
        href = link.get_attribute("href")
        print(href)
        results.append(href)
    driver.close()
    return results
    
get_results(pesquisa)
```

In try-except, you need to pass after exception block to run the following statements. If not, they are cancelled.